# Cakephp redirects to /app/webroot when using www before domain name

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

When I enter my domain name with 'www' for example http://domain.nl everything works fine but when I use the same domain with 'www' before it, it redirects to /app/webroot which gives errors. What could the problem be?

I use the default cakephp .htaccess files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The problem most likely lies in your virtual host. Can you show the vhost entry for the site please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Check first your rewrite mode is on or not in `apache\conf\httpd.conf` file

check below code in `httpd.conf` file

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

hash remove in this line and restart apache server

After then you can set

```
RewriteBase /YOURPATH/
```

Or

```
RewriteBase /
```

in htacess

I think you can try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /YOURPATH/
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]

 </IfModule>
```